# Jest + ts-jest tries to transpile ESM from node_modules

Tags: typescript, jestjs, es6-modules, ts-jest

My directory structure is like so:

```
project
|-- package.json
|-- tsconfig.json
|-- jest.config.cjs
|-- src
|   |-- index.ts
|   `-- foo.ts
`-- test
    |-- index.test.ts
    `-- helpers.ts
```

`package.json`:

```
[...]
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "testExp": "NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules jest"
  }
[...]
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.7",
    "typescript": "^4.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "image-type": "^5.2.0"
  }
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

`jest.config.cjs`:

```
module.exports = {
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$': '$1',
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts$': [
      'ts-jest',
      {
        useESM: true,
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

`src/foo.ts`:

```
// import imageType from 'image-type'

export const foo = (word: string): string => {
  // imageType(Buffer.from('abcd', 'utf-8'))
  return `not ${word}`
}
```

`src/index.ts`:

```
// import imageType from 'image-type'

export const foo = (word: string): string => {
  // try {
  //   imageType(Buffer.from('abcd', 'utf-8')) // import/use it just to prove a point!
  // } catch {}
  return `not ${word}`
}
```

`test/helpers.ts`:

```
export const logStuff = (a: string): string => {
  console.log(a)
  return a
}
```

`test/index.test.ts`:

```
import { expect, jest, test, describe } from '@jest/globals'

import { concat } from '../src/index'
import { logStuff } from './helpers'

describe('some test suite', () => {
  test('some test', () => {
    const res = logStuff(concat('some', 'stuff'))

    expect(res).toEqual('some not stuff')
  })
})
```

I have 2 separate issues with the above configuration:

1. running `npm run test` works fine, but when I uncomment the usage of `image-type` module (ES module) I get an error (it looks like something is still trying to transpile it?):

   ```
   Jest encountered an unexpected token

       Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

       Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

       By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

       Here's what you can do:
        • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
        • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
        • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
        • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
        • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

       You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
       https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
       For information about custom transformations, see:
       https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

       Details:

       /Users/danielgruszczyk/workspace/priv/jest-ts-test/node_modules/image-type/index.js:1
       ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import {fileTypeFromBuffer} from 'file-type';
                                                                                         ^^^^^^

       SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

       > 1 | import imageType from 'image-type'
   ```
2. when running `npm run testExp` nothing works, instead I get the following error:

   ```
       ReferenceError: exports is not defined

         1 | import { expect, jest, test, describe } from '@jest/globals'
       > 2 |
           | ^
         3 | import { concat } from '../src/index.js'
         4 | // import { logStuff } from './helpers'
         5 |

         at test/index.test.ts:2:23
   ```

What is going wrong and where?

I published the code into a GitHub repo:
https://github.com/codan84/jest-ts-experiments